# Unable to see launch slave agents on Unix machines via SSH on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have two different Jenkins instances with different versions.
One has version 1.609.1 and when I create a slave on it I see options in the launch method like:

- *"Launch slaves agents on a Unix machine via SSH"*
- *"Launch slave agents via Java web start"*
- *"Launch slaves via execution of command on the master and let Jenkins control this Windows slave as a Windows service"*

I have one more instance that is of version 2.89.4, but the slave launch option is different - it has one *"Launch slaves agent via SSH". The rest of the all options are the same.

Is this slave launching option something version-specific?

Answer (score 5):

It is specific to the plugin. You need to add it in your missing instance. See *[SSH Slaves Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin)*.